# Binding DataContext to custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to bind a value in a customcontrol placed inside a DataGridTemplateColumn but the binding doesn't seem to work.

My DataGridTemplateColumn :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" SortMemberPath="Etat" CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="True" x:Name="colonneEtat">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate />
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <widget:MyWidget MyObject="{Binding MyObjectVariable, Converter={StaticResource MyDebugConverter}}" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My custom control contains just a Grid for now but it has a property defined as follow :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyObjectProperty=
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyObject",
            typeof(ObjectType),
            typeof(MyWidget),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
public ObjectType MyObject
        {
            get { return (ObjectType)GetValue(MyObjectProperty); }
            set { 
                SetValue(MyObjectProperty, value);
                FillCustomControl();
            }
        }
```

Debug Converter is just a dummy converter to test the binding :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
               object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            return value;
        }
```

My custom controls works fine, I've already tried it in another place of my application. Its functioning is simple : When the property is set I Fill the custom control depending of the content from the property. As said this behavior has been tested.

But in the case of this DataGridTemplateColumn the property is never set. I don't have any binding error in the output and the debugger stops in the converter + the value in the converter is the value expected. But for some reason it doesn't set the value of the property inside my custom control.

What am I missing ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm confused.  Your `MyObject` property is defined on `MyWidget`, but your usage of `MyWidget` uses a property called `ObjectProperty` and tries to bind that to `MyObject`.  What is `ObjectProperty`?  Where is this column?

Comment: Indeed two objects with the same name... I've changed but still not working.

Comment: I wasn't implying this was why it didn't work, it was unclear what you were attempting to do.  We still don't know where `MyObjectVariable` is, what you might be doing with `DataContext`' in `MyWidget` internally etc.  It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that someone could reproduce your issue.  Answers will be guesses at best.

Comment: Using snoop I'm able to see that my property is set but the "set" method of my property is never called and I guess that's the problem. I'll use a changed event on the Dependencyproperty to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You should omit the `Property` part of the `DependencyProperty` when data binding to it, so instead of this:

```
<widget:MyWidget ObjectProperty="{Binding MyObject ... }" />
```

You should use this:

```
<widget:MyWidget MyObject="{Binding MyObject ...}" />
```

Unless you actually have another `DependencyProperty` named `ObjectPropertyProperty` defined in your `Widget` class. Also, according to your code, the object that is set as the `DataContext` for the `DataGrid` should have a property named `MyObject` as well.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ok, now I understand your problem. That is that the setter of the CLR property that relates to a `DependencyProperty` is *never* called by the Framework... that CLR property is for *your* use only. If you want to do something when a `DependencyProperty` value is changed, then you need to set up a [`PropertyChangedCallback` handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.110).aspx). You can do that like this (from the linked page on MSDN):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AquariumGraphicProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "AquariumGraphic",
  typeof(Uri),
  typeof(AquariumObject),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, 
      new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUriChanged)
  )
);

private static void OnUriChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  Shape sh = (Shape) d;
  sh.Fill = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage((Uri)e.NewValue));
}
```

In fact, you can even ignore the `PropertyChangedCallback` constructor and declare it like this too:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AquariumGraphicProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("AquariumGraphic", typeof(Uri), typeof(AquariumObject), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, 
    OnUriChanged));
```

Comment: Indeed thank you, error when I pasted the code... Fixed. The property has the right name and MyObject contains a value (as I can check in the Debug Converter). But the "set" is never called. I've tried to put an "object"  but same problem.